# Renaming many-to-many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:
`User`, `Artist` and `Following`

`User - Artist` association is many-to-many through `Following`.

`Following` table has `user_id` and `artist_id` fields.

How can I setup this association so I could use:

```
User.find(123).followed_artists
Artist.find(234).followers
```

As I'm getting lost with all these parameters, class_name, source, foreign_key.

Comment: How are your associations being implemented? `has_many through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: @MurifoX - `has_many through` its right there in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets say you have a run of the mill many to many setup:

```
class User
  has_many :followings
  has_many :artists, through: :following
end

class Following
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artists
  has_many :followings
  has_many :users, through: :following
end
```

Bear with me here, so far ActiveRecord can figure out by itself where to look for the target of the `through` relationship simply by deduction.

If we want to use a different name for the `artists` and `users` relations we just have to tell active record what association on Following to use:

```
class User
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followed_artists, through: :following, source: :artist
end

class Following
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artists
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers, through: :following, source: :user
end
```

We don't have to muck about with the `class_name` or `foreign_key` options as long as ActiveRecord can deduce it from the name of the relations on the join table.

However if that is not the case you would have to specify it on the join table. Lets say some hipsters started mucking about in your app:

```
class Following
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'Persona', foreign_key: 'persona_id'
  belongs_to :artist, class_name: 'Artiste', foreign_key: 'artiste_id'
end
```

The same also applies if the relation name to the join model is not "conventional".

```
class User
  has_many :artist_followings, class_name: 'Following'
  has_many :followed_artists, through: :artist_followings, 
                              source: :artist
end

class Following
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

Comment: bless up, you saved me much pain